# Symfony2 + Doctrine OneToMany JOIN failing

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Trying to use the following code to join my 2 tables:

```
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT a, c FROM AppBundle:Auctions a JOIN a.catalog c');        

    $auctions = $query->getResult();
```

And getting the error:
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 53 near 'c': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Auctions has no association named catalog

My tables are defined like this:

Auctions.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Auctions
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="auctions")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Auctions
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Catalogs", mappedBy="auction")
 */
private $catalog;
}
```

And Catalogs.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Catalogs
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="catalogs", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="catalogs_FI_1", columns={"treasurer_info_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="catalogs_FI_2", columns={"auction_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="unique_stripped_name", columns={"stripped_name"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Catalogs
{
    /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Auctions
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Auctions", inversedBy="catalog")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="auction_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $auction;
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong here, it seems like all of the doctrine examples for OneToMany work like this? Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: updated the schema files and query being used.

Comment: What about using a repository for  Auction entity? You could create a query builder in a repository method and get query working more easily...

Answer (score 0):

You don't want your `OneToMany` association on your primary key.  What you want is another variable in your `Auctions` entity that relates to `Catalogs`:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Catalogs", mappedBy="auction")
 */
private $catalogs;
```

Then update your `Catalogs` entity:

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Auctions
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Auctions", inversedBy="catalogs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="auction_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $auction;
```

Then your join would look like this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT a, c FROM AppBundle:Auctions a JOIN a.catalogs c');
$auctions = $query->getResult();
```

What you want to remember when dealing with Doctrine is that you are thinking of your entities in terms of how they relate to each other, not how they would relate in a SQL query.  You're defining the `id` mappings inside your entity so that when you write `DQL` you can join based on your association rather than the actual column names.

Comment: Hmmm I tried this out verbatim and i'm still getting an error that there is no association named catalogs in AppBundle\Entity\Auctions

Comment: Can you post your updated Auctions entity after trying what I gave?

Comment: Of course!

Just updated both of the schema files and the query being used. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It all looks right off the top of my head...maybe clear all the cache folders out and retry the query?  Do you have the corresponding getters and setters?

Comment: I've cleared the cache many times to no avail. I have getters and setters, but nothing like getCatalog() in Auctions, which I'd expect to be getting. I've regenerated them after making changes with: 
    php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle

Comment: Are you sure you have the appropriate foreign key and not just an index in your catalog table?

Comment: Yeah, the catalogs table is defined with:
    CONSTRAINT `catalogs_FK_2` FOREIGN KEY (`auction_id`) REFERENCES `auctions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE

Pretty sure everything is good from a database perspective, been using this schema for years with symfony1, just rewriting for symfony2

Comment: At this point I would recommend auto-generating your entities with Doctrine and seeing what comes up

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately thats where these entities came from. It generated all the ManyToOne relationships but none of the OneToMany relationships.

Comment: Still, the OneToMany is simple enough to add, and make sure you have a getter on the `Auctions` entity like: `public function getCatalog() { return $this->catalog; }` (I would still recommend calling it `catalogs` since there could be many)